# Yii2 - Missing Widget - Assets when creating modal with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, widget, kartik-v

I have searched now very long for this but no answers, please help me.
I'm using the highchart-widget from 2amigos in yii2. When I'm creating a view in my controller via "render" the chart shows
[image: Asset inlcuded]

and as you can see on the picture on the right the asset is included in the source of the network -> "b732256a - highcharts.src.js"

BUT NOW COMES THE PROBLEM, when I'm rendering the view with "renderAjax" and insert the view in an existing HTML document with ajax -> take a look at my javascript code: the the asset "b732256a - highcharts.src.js" is missing take a look at this foto

[image: Asset Missing]

But when i access the action direct via browser:

index.php?r=bewt/ladeauswertung&standort=&datum=

it works with renderAjax and render, there is just a problem when i bind the view in an existing html document. im using this routine, to bind the view in an existing html document

```
document.getElementById("auswertungdetail").innerHTML = jsondata;
```

What you need to know about my code.
on a html-page there is a button, when the user press this button im calling the following javascript code, and the chart should show up without reloading the whole page

```
$(document).on('click', '#ladeauswertung', function ()
{
    var ausgewaehlterstandort = document.getElementById("standorte").value;
    var datum = document.getElementById("datum").value;

    $.get("index.php?r=voti/ladeauswertung&standort=" + ausgewaehlterstandort + "&datum=" + datum,
        function (jsondata)
        {
            document.getElementById("auswertungdetail").innerHTML = jsondata;
        }
    );
});
```

in my controller im rendering the view:

```
    function actionLadeauswertung($standort, $datum)
    {
     
        //some algorithm that do smth with $standort and $datum, not important
        $auswertung = 5;
        $gesamtauswertung = 10;
        
        return $this->renderAjax('auswertungdetail', ["auswertung" => $auswertung, "gesamtauswertung" => $gesamtauswertung]);
    }
```

and here ist the view which i render in the controller above:

```
<?php

use dosamigos\highcharts\HighCharts;

?>


         <?php echo
HighCharts::widget([
    'clientOptions' => [
        'chart' => [
                'type' => 'bar'
        ],
        'title' => [
             'text' => 'Fruit Consumption'
             ],
        'xAxis' => [
            'categories' => [
                'Apples',
                'Bananas',
            ]
        ],
        'yAxis' => [
            'title' => [
                'text' => 'Fruit eaten'
            ]
        ],
        'series' => [
            ['name' => 'Jane', 'data' => [1, 0, 4]],
            ['name' => 'John', 'data' => [5, 7, 3]]
        ]
    ]
]);
?>
```

and in my view im calling the 2amigos highchart, it works perfectly with "render" but i wanted to add the view where the highchart is included dynamically when a button is pressed so have to use renderAjax.

PLEASE HELP!!!!!

Comment: please provide the complete code for the issue you need to add the code for `action` adding a line for the `renderAjax` won't help, include the view also that is related to your issue to identify the correct issue

Comment: done, take a look now, please write a comment if you need smth else

Comment: Just to confirm, check console in browser. renderAjax doesnt render layout and you probably have AppAsset (including jQuery and other dependencies) there.

Comment: my console is empty, i think there is a problem with the DOM cause i add the "view" dynamic to the existing html document